# How to normalize a column with year's of experience using python regex?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning

I have lots of unique work experiences reported in my dataset. The survey format was not set strictly to be an integer, and this resulted in the collection of a shit ton of noise.

Above is a snapshot of all the unique years of experience.
[image: unique years of experience in the dataset]

---

It is a herculean task to identify and manually correct the undesirable entries to desirable ones. I wanted to explore the most efficient generic way of using regex to normalize the years of experience to float values.

I can think of the below strategy but I'm not proficient in using regex. So please guide me.

Strategy:

1. If there is no numeric value in the column, return np.nan
2. If there is a huge number 3 or more digits return np.nan
3. If the response is in the format "number (2) [some string starting with y] followed by number (7) [some string starting with m]" return number.number (2.7)
4. If the response has only a number (7 yrs) followed by some string starting with y, return the number.
5. if the response has only a number (6 mnths) followed by some string starting with m, return the number after a decimal (.6)
6. if there is a range of numbers return the topmost number.
   Ex (0_-_10) return 10, (20 - 25) return 25
7. If there is only a number but no string starting with y or m after the number return the number
   They can be pure numbers or strings like (above 25, 17+, >15, 4.5(Ongoing), ...)
8. Handle numbers with years and month not separated by space (Ex: 20YEAR 11Month)

As you can see that there is a lot of variation in the spelling error of the year and month, I believe the above strategy might work. You are welcome to give alternate suggestions.

Please find the dataset here: https://gist.github.com/skwolvie/9a545ee5eea1db28b9933fbc17f1f13e

Comment: I would rather simplify this by extracting from `yoe` the first number I encounter (first match for each row) using a regex (`[\d\.]+`), then check for the word 'month' inside `yoe` and transform the extracted number in a decimal. There will be some information loss for sure, though it would be acceptable as long as you get a number as a starting point (for years or months).

Comment: fair enough. But if you look at the dataset in the link you can see exceptional cases where it might not hold water. For instance some have given year, phone number, ...

Comment: If there are other additional infos that the user has added, and there's a way to recognize them with respect to the years of experience, then it's all about crafting a good regex that can catch it. If you can't distinguish in any ways between the no of years and let's say the civic no where they live, then it will fail. One useful constraint you suggested on `yoe` is the length of the number: that could be a starting point to avoid phone numbers at all.

Comment: You could use something like this to investigate different patterns that are present:  `df['yoe'].str.lower().str.extractall('\d.*([Yy][A-Za-z]*)').value_counts()`

Comment: @jch good suggestion. However, my end goal is to just remove all noises and have float or int values in the yoe column. Some cases mentioned in point 6,7, 8 are crucial to handle as they cover 25% of the non missing values in the dataset. Can you recommend how to accomplish all the 8 cases using regex? I figured out the first 4, trying to achieve the remaining. Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: For 6 - `df['yoe'].str.lower().str.extractall('\d{1,2}[\s_]{0,1}-[\s_]{0,1}(\d{1,2})').value_counts()`

Comment: For 8 - `df['yoe'].str.lower().str.extractall('((\d{1,2}).*years.*(\d{1,2}).*months)')`  Remove the outer capture group.  Hard because there are a number of ways to specify years and months.  Like yrs and mos.  8yrs7mos.

Comment: For 7 this might get you closer - `df['yoe'].str.lower().str.extractall('((\d{1,2})\W{0,3}[a-ln-xz][a-z]*)')`  Still not perfect.  Matches things like 3 weeks.

Comment: A starter for 5, `df['yoe'].str.lower().str.extractall('(^(\d{1,3})\W{0,3}[m][a-z]*)')`  You'd have to take the output and do decimal placement.

Comment: Also some 'months' only entries, they are greater than 12.  So need some calculation.